# Simple heart-shaped click counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I am trying to make a heart-shaped click counter, only one click is allowed and it would add 1 to the number beginning with 1280.  The heart shape start with no color, but when clicked it will switch to a red heart.  Here is the quote I tried but the number does not increase when I click on the heart.  :(  :(

Can somebody please look at the code and say which part is wrong?

```js
$('body').on('click', '.share-icons a.heart24', function(event){
 event.defaultPrevented;
 console.log('heart');

function log_quote_heart(id, place, ac_type, t, pp, current_object){
//    if(t === 't') return;

 if($(current_object).hasClass('heart24-on')){

  return;
 }

var heartLink = $('.wrap-block[data-id="'+id+'"] a.heart24');
    
    $(heartLink).removeClass('heart24-off').addClass('heart24-on');
    heartLink.html(+heartLink.html()+1);
```

```css
.heart24-on {
    background: url(//www.azquotes.com/public2/images/heart24-on.png) no-repeat!important;
    background-size: 24px auto!important;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.heart24 a {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #a94c1c;
}


.heart24 {text-decoration:none}
.heart24 {position:relative;top:0!important;display:inline-block;margin-right:4px;width:24px;height:24px;border-radius:50%}
.heart24 a{font-weight:500;color:#a94c1c}
.heart24-on{background:url(//www.azquotes.com/public2/images/heart24-on.png) no-repeat!important;background-size:24px auto!important;border-radius:0}
.heart24-off{background:url(//www.azquotes.com/public2/images/heart24-off.png) no-repeat!important;background-size:24px auto!important;border-radius:0}
.heart24{vertical-align:top;background-position-x:0;padding-left:31px;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:0;line-height:20px;font-size:12px}
```

```html
<a class="heart24 heart24-off" href="javascript:void(0);">1280</a>
```

Comment: Check out my answer please.

Comment: Please tick as green checked answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Elman.  I just ticked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer please:

```
$(function(){

            $(document).on('click', '.heart24', function(event){

                    event.preventDefault();


                    var heartCount = +$(this).text();
                    if(heartCount == 1280){
                        heartCount++;
                        $(this).removeClass('heart24-off');
                        $(this).addClass('heart24-on');
                        $(this).text(heartCount);
                    }
                    else{
                        heartCount--;
                        $(this).removeClass('heart24-on');
                        $(this).addClass('heart24-off');
                        $(this).text(heartCount);
                    }



            })

        });
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  Your answer is the best (for me) because when I click, it increases by 1 but when i click again , it lowers by 1

Answer (score 0):

Your JS has been incomplete, syntactically invalid and partially flawed. Moreover the html fragment did not match the selectors you were using in the code.

The following snippet *probably* does what you want. You might need to further constrain the selectors for the `a.heart` element according to the context in your target site.

```js
    $('body').on('click', 'a.heart24', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log('heart');

//***        function log_quote_heart(id, place, ac_type, t, pp, current_object) {
        //    if(t === 't') return;
        if ($(event.target).hasClass('heart24-on')) {
         return;
        }

        var heartLink = $('a.heart24');
        
     $(heartLink).removeClass('heart24-off').addClass('heart24-on');
     $(heartLink).text(+heartLink.text()+1);
    });
```

```css
    .heart24-on {
        background: url(//www.azquotes.com/public2/images/heart24-on.png) no-repeat!important;
        background-size: 24px auto!important;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    .heart24 a {
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #a94c1c;
    }


    .heart24 {text-decoration:none}
    .heart24 {position:relative;top:0!important;display:inline-block;margin-right:4px;width:24px;height:24px;border-radius:50%}
    .heart24 a{font-weight:500;color:#a94c1c}
    .heart24-on{background:url(//www.azquotes.com/public2/images/heart24-on.png) no-repeat!important;background-size:24px auto!important;border-radius:0}
    .heart24-off{background:url(//www.azquotes.com/public2/images/heart24-off.png) no-repeat!important;background-size:24px auto!important;border-radius:0}
    .heart24{vertical-align:top;background-position-x:0;padding-left:31px;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:0;line-height:20px;font-size:12px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <a class="heart24 heart24-off" href="javascript:void(0);">1280</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your comment and help.  Yes, my code was very bad... I am just beginning to learn about JS.. it's very hard :(

Comment: Can I ask, why do you add <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> in the html code?  usually <script> </script> is added around the JS code, right?

Comment: You are using the jQuery library which needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Consider just ising the `.toggleClass()` option. Example code:

```js
$(function() {
  function toggleHeart(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var self = $(ev.target);
    var count = parseInt(self.text());
    if (self.hasClass("heart24-on")) {
      return false;
    }
    self.toggleClass("heart24-off heart24-on");
    self.html(++count);
  }

  $(".heart24").click(toggleHeart);
});
```

```css
.heart24 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #a94c1c;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0!important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50% font-weight: 500;
  color: #a94c1c vertical-align: top;
  background-position: 0;
  padding-left: 31px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px
}

.heart24-on {
  background: url(//www.azquotes.com/public2/images/heart24-on.png) no-repeat!important;
  background-size: 24px auto!important;
  border-radius: 0
}

.heart24-off {
  background: url(//www.azquotes.com/public2/images/heart24-off.png) no-repeat!important;
  background-size: 24px auto!important;
  border-radius: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="heart24 heart24-off" href="#">1280</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, especially in cleaning my CSS.

Comment: @sunflowerhk Welcome. There wasn't anything "wrong" with the CSS, yet if you have repeats, you might make a change early that then gets changed back later in CSS without you knowing. Remember to pick one of the answers and mark it as the selected answer.